# how to color the whole star icon when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, codeigniter

I'm doing a project in codeIgniter and i have a form which is used to rate a product.

When i clicked a button(star) i need to make the whole button(star) to change its

colour into yellow.I did this but it only changes the border colour into yellow.Middle

of the button remains in white. 
 can anyone please explain me how to do that?

```
<h1><div class="rating" style="width:200px;float:left;padding-left:1px">
                                    <span id="span1" onclick="document.getElementById

('rateText').innerHTML='Excellent', setColor(this.id);">   ?   </span> 
                                    <span id="span2" onclick="document.getElementById

('rateText').innerHTML='Good', setColor(this.id);">   ?   </span> 
                                    <span id="span3" onclick="document.getElementById

('rateText').innerHTML='Okay', setColor(this.id);">   ?   </span>
                                    <span id="span4" onclick="document.getElementById

('rateText').innerHTML='Unsatisfied', setColor(this.id);">   ?   </span>
                                    <span id="span5" onclick="document.getElementById

('rateText').innerHTML='Terrible', setColor(this.id);">   ?   </span>
                                    </div></h1>

<div style="float:right;padding-right:450px">
        <h3><p id="rateText"></p></h3>
</div>
```

Javascript
This code changes the button colour when button is clicked

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setColor(btn){
    var property = document.getElementById(btn);
    property.style.color = "#FFFF00"
}
</script>
```

CSS
This code link the buttons and change colour on mouse hover

```
<style type="text/css">
    #rateText{

    text-align:right;

    }
    .rating {
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: rtl ;
    }

    .rating > span:hover:before,
    .rating > span:hover ~ span:before {
    content: "\2605";
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFFF00;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: Well looks like you are not using a solid star so that is why only the border changes since that is all that character has.

Comment: can you show me a example how to use solid star please @epascarello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the same style as for :hover selector. For instance you can add `.active` class to clicked star. Check the css and js code below.

```
.rating > span.active:before,
.rating > span:hover:before,
.rating > span:hover ~ span:before
{
    content: "\2605";
    position: absolute;
    color: #FFFF00;
}

function setColor(btn){
        var property = document.getElementById(btn);
        property.classList.add('active');
}
```

Comment: and here when i click a button span1 i need all the 5 buttons should be coloured but if i clicked span2 button that 5th button should change the colour into its normal way and all the other 4 buttons should appear in yellow colour can you please guide me to how to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gviI2E4Np4P7ET3ywIBc?p=preview). I hope it'll give you a clue.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much . You solved my problem :-) :-)